# Why do <a> tags actually exist?

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I was just wondering about this. Why do `<a>` tags actually exist? Surely the better way to add a link to an element is by allowing an href on any element so that it can function as a link to another place.

For example say, currently you have an album:

```
<div class="album">
  <a class="album__link" href="[url]">
    <img src="[source]" class="album__photo" />
    <h2 class="album__title">[title]</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

Surely the above could be better written like:

```
<div class="album" href="[url]">
  <img src="[source]" class="album__photo" />
  <h2 class="album__title">[title]</h2>
</div>
```

Just wondered what everyones thoughts on this were. Might be a silly question but if I don't ask then I won;t get to hear what anyone else thinks will I?

Comment: Different tags give the rendering device and or reading device ( like search engines) information about the page. You can write most html with a simply div tag if you want, but all the other tags combine to translate information to the browsers etc.

Comment: This question is not fit for a Q&A site like Stack Overflow. Opinion-based questions are offtopic. `Just wondered what everyones thoughts on this were` and `hear what anyone else thinks` are signs that your "question" cannot really be answered.

Answer (score 4):

You can already do

```
<a class="album" href="[url]">
  <img src="[source]" class="album__photo" />
  <h2 class="album__title">[title]</h2>
</a>
```

in HTML5. What is the problem with this? A `<div>` does not have any meaning, so I don't think it is necessary here. If you need a block container, just set `display: block` on your link (`.album`) from CSS.

What makes you think `<a>` is an unnecessary tag? Are there any necessary tags in your view? How do you plan supporting link-related features that are currently handled by [`<a>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html) (`target`, `rel`, `hreflang`, etc.)?

Comment: Would it be valid HTML5 code? In earlier versions you shouldn't place as here h2 in a, so it was necessary to create 2 links - one for image, one for h2 inside it

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek It is valid. There is a link in my answer to the HTML5 spec, it says: `Although previous versions of HTML restricted the a element to only containing phrasing content (essentially, what was in previous versions referred to as “inline” content), the a element is now transparent; that is, an instance of the a element is now allowed to also contain flow content (essentially, what was in previous versions referred to as “block” content)—if the parent element of that instance of the a element is an element that is allowed to contain flow content.`

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using [`href` on any element was a feature of the now abandoned XHTML 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/mod-hyperAttributes.html#adef_hyperAttributes_href). However, it causes too many problems.

Many HTML elements already have click activation behaviour that would clash with the link behaviour, so web authors would have to remember which elements `href` could be used on, and which couldn't.

Also, the `href` attribute doesn't live on its own. It comes with others like `target`, `download`, `rel`, `hreflang` and `type` which would also need to be put on each element. That in turn would cause a clash with the meaning of the `type` attribute on other elements.

So it has been considered, and it's just too messy, compared with having a dedicated element to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between setting href="" to a <div> and an <a> is that they have different display types. On a <div> it will select the whole block (display: block;) so you can click everywhere in the div and open the link and on an <a> it will only select the text.

Comment: You can simply put `display: inline` on a div too.